# Compile after assigning directive to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add a directive to an HTML element on a specific event through jQuery `.attr()`. This directive does not do its work after adding it.

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("myDirective", function() {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function () {
            alert("Hello");
        }
    });
```

When I use it directly in html, it works fine:

```
<div id="myDiv" my-directive></div>
```

But when I try adding it after a while with jQuery:

```
$("#myDiv").attr("my-directive", "")
```

it does not do anything.

How can I add a directive to an HTML element in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding it dynamically when all the compilation is performed, you need to recompile it in order the directive to apply.

```
$("#myDiv").attr("my-directive", "");
var elem = $("#myDiv");
$compile(elem )($scope);
$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶a̶p̶p̶l̶y̶(̶)̶;̶
```

Inject the $compile in controller. The compilation is done on jQuery element(which is non angular context),  ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶ ̶`̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶a̶p̶p̶l̶y̶(̶)̶;̶`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention it

Comment: It works fine with your solution actually without `$scope.$apply();`.
When I used `$scope.$apply();`, it throws an error:
`Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress at Scope.$apply`

Comment: @georgeawg, can you please explain why $scope.$apply() is not required as jquery code is non-angular context.

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS **execution context.** Since the code is **executed** inside the AngularJS **execution context**, `$apply` is not necessary. At any point in time there can be only one `$digest` or `$apply` operation in progress. The [$rootScope:inprog Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog) prevents very hard to detect bugs from entering the application.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. you need to recompile it dynamically using `$compile`

```
$("#myDiv").attr("my-directive", "");
$("#myDiv").html($compile($("#myDiv").html())($scope));
 ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶a̶p̶p̶l̶y̶(̶)̶;̶
```

But getting element using `$` is not a good solution. `$` is very precious. So, store the element in one variable to not to get each time.

```
var element = $("#myDiv");
element.attr("my-directive", "");
element.html($compile(element.html())($scope));
 ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶a̶p̶p̶l̶y̶(̶)̶;̶
```